# What to do if my question ban is not getting removed?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

I have read on the Physics S.E website that users get a chance to ask question after 6 months of question ban

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

but my question ban is not getting removed even after 6 months,so what to do?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/ has a few important stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looking at your history, you [asked this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411600/kinematics-problem-invloving-position-and-time) less than 5 months ago.

According to the wording you provided yourself:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one **6 months after your last question**. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

You should still have about a month to wait before you can ask a single question.

My advice is to try to be careful when asking your question on the main site to avoid additional bans.  This question for example showed a lack of research or oversight; which can often lead to bad reception on the main site.

Comment: Yep, and it might be worth adding that any user who has access can take advantage of helpful people in [chat] to help prepare a question so that it has a better chance of being well received.

Comment: Chat is a resource that too few people use to their advantage.